# CSV (or excel) parsing ; eliminate empty column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel, csv

I am using `TextFieldParser` class to parse the file. I want to eliminate or ignore complete column if "entire column" is empty (which means single empty cell of a perticular row should be considered) Is this possible?

Note: as per functionality, I need to use data copied to clipboard. So can not pass direct file path to the parser.

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(row));
string[] delimiters = { ",", "\t" };
parser.SetDelimiters(delimiters);
string[] columns = null;
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
columns = parser.ReadFields();
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I get that English may be a second language but not clear.  "which means single empty cell of a perticular row should be considered"

Comment: Is it column or row you want to eliminate?

Comment: *I want to eliminate or ignore complete column*

Comment: I want to eliminate "column".

Comment: @Blam; if there is intermediate empty cell; for example: row 1 data (a1, a2, a3) and row 2 data (x1, "" ,x3); here empty cell should be considered

Comment: That language is not clear.  If two cells are empty that is not a single empty cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through the [`TextFieldParser` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) page on MSDN, I see that there is nothing written there that would make me think that this class can ignore a whole column. That would be something that you would have to do manually.  Furthermore, your code does not seem right because you are trying to read the fields repeatedly with the same variable:

```
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    columns = parser.ReadFields();
}
```

Comment: any suggestions on doing it effectively?

Comment: Yeah... put all of your `string` arrays into a `List<string[]>` and then manually iterate through each array and copy each column value into a column in a smaller array. There are lots of different ways to do this, but in all cases, you'll have to write some procedural code as you loop through each array.